# Creating navigation between Unity3D instantiated UI elements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So in Unity3D I have a script that reads a JSON delivered by a database and converts every field into an `UnityEngine.UI` `InputField` so the user can edit the entry. The code literally instantiates an `InputField` prefab.

The problem is there is no navigation between them, if I just press TAB or any arrow key the focus won't change, and that is not only very user-unfriendly but also annoying.

So my question here is if there is a way by code to change the navigation in the moment I instantiate them, or if should I just go straight making myself a script for that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cant set the TabNr Property of the Inputfield programmatically?

Comment: what do you mean by TabNr? I can't find that in the docs :/

Comment: Every control in Windows has a TabNr or TabStop Property which does exactly what you need. But maybe it's different in Controls for Unity. In this case you will need to write your own script for the navigation.

Comment: Have you checked http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/tab-between-input-fields.263779/

Comment: Hi @KarmaEDV this is for Unity/, nothing to do with windows.  It's quite annoying on the forum when a question is asked about Unity and the only way one knows that is the tag at the bottom!

Comment: I will take note ! :P

Comment: Actually no hahahaha Since the prefabs are instatiated in runtime one by one the navigation brokes ( i guess? ). And I found out you can set up the navigation by script, but that only takes care of arrow keys. So I made myself a simple script that navigates through the inputFields by the TAB button, and also the SHIFT+TAB to go backwards. Guess that's what I should have done in the first place :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can set those programmatically

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Navigation.html

[image]

Suggest you first just set up some buttons in the Editor, and experiment with it in the editor.  THen, get in to doing it in code.

It's the most powerful / unknown feature in Unity!